# Why is there a runtime error in this code?

Tags: java, string, runtime, substring

My penney game for 40 character string ends with a runtime error, can someone help me understand why? The code just needs to tell the number of combinations in a string.

Here is an example:

Input:

```
4                                 1                        
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH                       2      
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT                              
3                              
HHTTTHHTTTHTHHTHHTTHTTTHHHTHTTHTTHTTTHTH                             
4                  HTHTHHHTHHHTHTHHHHTTTHTTTTTHHTTTTHTHHHHT
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 38                  2 38 0 0 0 0 0 0 0        
3 4 7 6 4 7 4 5 1                   4 6 3 4 5 3 6 5 6
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t;
    t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while((t--)!=0)
    {
      int N,i,j;
      N=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      int c []={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
      String arr [] ={"TTT","TTH","THT","THH","HTT","HTH","HHT","HHH"};
      String str,str1;
      N=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      str=br.readLine();
      for(i=0;i<=37;i++)
      {   
        str1="";
        str1=str.substring(i,i+3);
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
          if(str1.equals(arr[j]))
          {
            c[j]++;
            break;
          } 
        }
      }
      System.out.print(N);
      for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        System.out.print(" "+c[i]);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

> Runtime error time: 0.1 memory: 320576 signal:-1

Comment: sorry... just now added the error obtained

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your program. This is now showing the iteration number in front of the string being input :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Please enter number of iterations : ");
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for(int counter=1; counter<= t;  counter++)
        {
            int c []={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            String arr [] = {"TTT","TTH","THT","THH","HTT","HTH","HHT","HHH"};
            System.out.print(counter + " ");
            String str = br.readLine();

            for(int i=0; i<str.length()-3; i++)
            {
                String str1 = str.substring(i,i+3);

                for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
                {
                    if(str1.equals(arr[j]))
                    {
                        c[j]++;
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                System.out.print(" "+c[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
     }
}
```

And it is working.

Comment: Not sure what is the purpose of N=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

Comment: It was asked in the problem that each string will be preceeded by a number.... like for 1st string 1,for 2nd string 2 and so on......

Comment: The error you are facing is somewhat related to memory error. I couldn't understand what your code is doing so I started with a clean slate. But now the code is what you are asking. Please let me know if this is working for you,